# jqGrid with custom cell colors

Tags: jquery, grid, jqgrid

Is it possible in jqGrid(jquery grid http://www.trirand.com/blog/) to have custom cell text colors e.g. in price column i want red if price > 100$ and green if price < 50$ else grey?

More generally do

1. jqGrid provides hooks to change grid cellview, e.g. i can register a callback whenver cells of price column are created or modified.
2. or is it possible to have separate model and view (client side)
   e.g. from server i can send two data for each row i.e. how to display and what to display

Edit: so here is an example showing the sample formatter, which colors the cell based on value

```
function infractionInFormatter(el, cellval, opts)
{
    $(el).html(cellval).css('color',infraction_color_map[cellval]);
}

colModel :[ 
    ...
    {name:'date', index:'date', width:120, date:true}, 
    {name:'inf_out', index:'inf_out', width:60, formatter:infractionInFormatter,},
    ...
],
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Write a [custom formatter](http://www.secondpersonplural.ca/jqgriddocs/_2kn0mlo1p.htm). This is just a function that you pass a reference to in your colModel. You get a reference to the final cell selector in the function, so anything you can do with jQuery you can do in a formatter. Including change the color/style.

Answer (score 2):

You can also specify the class in the colModel:

```
colModel: [
           {
            name:'field_x', 
            index:'field_x',  
            align: 'left',  
            width:  35, 
            classes: 'cvteste'
           },
          .....
          ]
```

Answer (score -1):

I would set a red background colour if a cell has xxx value, else a green background if the value is yyy.

I have wrote this code:

```
.....
colModel:[
    {name:'id',index:'id', width:15,hidden:true, align:"center"},
    {name:'title',index:'title', width:150, align:"center"},
    {name:'start',index:'start', width:350, align:"center", sorttype:"date"},
    {name:'fine',index:'fine', width:350, align:"center", sorttype:"date"},
    {name:'completed',index:'completed', width:120, align:"center",formatter:infractionInFormatter},        
    ],
.....
```

And this function like your example:

```
function infractionInFormatter(el, cellval, opts)
        {
            .....
        }
```

How I have to set it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This isn't an answer at all. Go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you want to ask a question.